# Why can't you cancel an upvote on a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments

I think there should be functionality to cancel an upvote on a comment. For example I was speaking with someone in response to a question I asked and I was on my phone. I [easily &] accidentally clicked the upvote on that persons comment and it definitely didn't deserve an upvote as it was just two people communicating about a problem.

Comment: Can you not already undo comment votes?

Comment: You can undo comment upvotes by clicking on that vote. (Unless you already clicked on it, and chose "cancel", it seems)

Comment: @Cerbrus You probably just hit the time limit (60 seconds) on your test of that scenario- I just tried that and was able to undo an upvote on a comment after having chose "cancel."

Comment: Hm, so it seems, @Kendra. Weird.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You *can* undo an upvote on a comment, [but only within the first 60 seconds *if* you did not navigate away or refresh the page.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129032/266735)

To do this, as with other votes and as pointed out in Andy's [answer,](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302515/2607247) you just click the upvote arrow again.

Do note, however, that if you *do* cancel your upvote on a comment, it cannot be reupvoted.

Comment: Aha - that's why I am unable to undo it.

Comment: What is the rationale behind not being able to reupvote a comment?

Comment: I have the same doubt, haven't find the answer yet

Answer (score 6):

Click on the upvote arrow a second time. That will cancel your upvote after you confirm the following dialog:

[image: Cancel Upvote comment - Browser]

Or if you are using the mobile app:

[image: Cancel Upvote comment - App]

Comment: Why doesn't this work over on SO?

Comment: The screenshot, above, is from SO.

Comment: I just went and tried to click on the upvote arrow a second time and it does not bring that dialog box up. I did just try upvoting a comment here and I do get that diaglog. It's strange... *EDIT* It appears that it must be done within 60 seconds.

Comment: Your answer is correct in that you can undo upvotes on comments, and in showing how. But there are restrictions on _when_ you can remove an upvote on a comment, which I've outlined in my answer. (As you had already mentioned how to undo an upvote, I cited your answer for fairness.)