# Cancel upvotes on older comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, upvotes

I understand that comments are second class citizens and that they could be deleted at any time. While [a badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/94/pundit) can be earned from comment votes, no one gets any rep points from them. As it stands now, if you upvote a comment you can cancel the upvote within 60 seconds (which is an improvement from [the original design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129032/284743)).

From time to time I come across comments I upvoted in the past. They were helpful at the time, but for various reasons I no longer feel they are useful. When in a long comment list, I would prefer that my vote was not there highlighting the comment as useful. It's not that they are bad enough to flag for deletion. They are just no longer helpful in my opinion.

Since no rep points are involved, I don't see any harm in allowing us to cancel our old comment upvotes.

**Related**

- [Why can't you cancel an upvote on a comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302514/why-cant-you-cancel-an-upvote-on-a-comment) (clarification question, not a feature request)
- [Why are comment upvotes prevented after being undone?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311633/why-are-comment-upvotes-prevented-after-being-undone) (See the [top voted comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311633/why-are-comment-upvotes-prevented-after-being-undone#comment279240_311634) to the accepted answer there.)

Comment: If a comment is no longer useful, it's *obsolete* and should be flagged as such.

Comment: @Paulie_D, I often do flag obsolete comments for deletion. However, there are other times when it would be difficult (or incorrect) to convince a moderator that the comment is obsolete. I just want to remove my upvote from the comment. It's no longer useful *to me*. No need for moderator intervention.

Answer (score 3):

Comments are "second-class citizens" on SO. *Votes* on comments are even less important. Just as votes on posts are "locked" after a few minutes, votes on comments are also locked in after a period of time (though on a shorter timeframe). This reduces the "noise" on the site and also makes the site easier to run (fewer database hits, etc.).

If the comment is no longer helpful *to anyone*, flag it as obsolete. If it is no longer helpful *to you*, but might be helpful *to others*, then your vote still serves its purpose. **Best course of action: just move on.** Frankly, I don't see why you would care about this.

Comment: One caveat with the comparison between vote locks on posts and vote locks on comments: the vote lock is lifted from a post if it is edited. Comments cannot be edited after the grace period, so the lock cannot be lifted.

Comment: @TinyGiant this is true, but that's just part of the second-class nature of a comment. There's no need to edit comments after a very limited period of time; either the comment still serves a purpose as written, or it doesn't and should be deleted.

Comment: I think you're missing my point. Yes comments can't be edited, that's fine, That's the reasoning I'm using for justifying the vote lock being lifted on comments. There is no action that can be taken on a comment to trigger a need to change the vote.

Comment: @TinyGiant My point is basically a parallel to your last sentence. You say, "There is no action that can be taken on a comment to trigger a need to change the vote." I agree, depending on how you read that. There is no action that can be taken on a comment to *justify* a possibility of changing the vote. Either the comment is still helpful or it's not. If not, flag it. If you don't think a flag is justified, then neither is a vote retraction, and there's nothing to do but move on.

Comment: I think you think I think you're wrong. I think you're wrong to think that I think that you're wrong.

Comment: @TinyGiant That is probably the most Stack Overflow-y comment ever. Nicely done. :)